# Lighter javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've build this simple interactive scenario. Now everything seems working fine except that when start `for` loop as below. What can I do to fasten the script?

here the full code http://codepen.io/Angussimons/pen/oZmNer

Thanks in advance

```
for (let i = 0; i < manNumber; i++) {

  // Definisco quale strada
  if (i < (manNumber * leftStreet)) {
    street[i] = document.getElementById('path-2');

  } else {
    street[i] = document.getElementById('path-1');
  }

  // genero una velocità per ognuno
  _speed[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
  _speed[i] = (_speed[i]/1000);

  let shiftTop = -1.5;

  // genero una posizione su ognuno
  let manPosition = shiftTop + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) - 500)/1000;

  // vario la durata dei gesti
  var _duration = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 500);

  mansHead.push( new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.omini',
    className:        'omino man-head-'+i,
    shape:            'circle',
    radius:           8,
    fill:             manColor,
    top:              manPosition+'%',
    left:             0,
    x:                {0 : 5},
    y:                10,
    easing:           'linear.none',
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    x:                {5 : 0},
  }));
  mansBody.push(new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.man-head-'+i,
    className:        'man-body-'+i,
    shape:            'line',
    fill:             'none',
    stroke:           manColor,
    radius:           10,
    strokeWidth:      13,
    strokeLinecap:    'round',
    angle:            {85 : 95},
    x:                {5 : -2},
    y:                30,
    easing:           'linear.none',
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    angle:            {95 : 85},
    x:                {[-2] : 5},
    y:                30,
  }));
  mansArmL.push(new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.man-body-'+i,
    className:        'man-arm-'+i,
    shape:            'line',
    fill:             'none',
    stroke:           manColor,
    radius:           10,
    strokeWidth:      6,
    strokeLinecap:    'round',
    angle:            {45 : -45},
    x:                -5,
    y:                {8 : -8},
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    angle:            {[-45] : 45},
    y:                {[-8] : 8},
  }));
  mansArmR.push(new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.man-body-'+i,
    className:        'man-arm-'+i,
    shape:            'line',
    fill:             'none',
    stroke:           manColor,
    radius:           10,
    strokeWidth:      6,
    strokeLinecap:    'round',
    angle:            {[-45] : 45},
    x:                -5,
    y:                {[-8] : 8},
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    angle:            {45 : -45},
    y:                {8 : -8},
  }));
  mansLegL.push(new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.man-body-'+i,
    className:        'man-leg-'+i,
    shape:            'line',
    fill:             'none',
    stroke:           manColor,
    radius:           12,
    strokeWidth:      7,
    strokeLinecap:    'round',
    angle:            {20 : -20},
    x:                22,
    y:                {8 : -8},
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    angle:            {[-20] : 20},
    x:                22,
    y:                {[-8] : 8},
  }));
  mansLegR.push(new mojs.Shape({
    parent:           '.man-body-'+i,
    className:        'man-leg-'+i,
    shape:            'line',
    fill:             'none',
    stroke:           manColor,
    radius:           12,
    strokeWidth:      7,
    strokeLinecap:    'round',
    angle:            {[-20] : 20},
    x:                22,
    y:                {[-8] : 8},
    duration:         _duration,
  }).then({
    angle:            {20 : -20},
    x:                22,
    y:                {8 : -8},
  }));
}
```

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: Ask this in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Robert that is too slow when loading these 100 small mans in the animation. Il would like to know if there are any suggestion to improve performance of the script.

Comment: Ok, didn't see that. It runs perfectly well here.

Comment: @Robert Also on mobile is slow and sometimes glitchy.